# Views URL GET Query exceeding apache2 maximum limit

Tags: views, uri

I am building a views based report that allows selection of fields using views dynamic fields [https://www.drupal.org/project/views_dynamic_fields]. The view also has more than 15 filters for generating all possible reports.

The purpose is mostly administrative for generating variety of reports saving those reports [URL based specific report - selecting fields and filters].

**The problem is that I am getting apache2 maximum URL Length issue.** I have followed the apache2 documentation for increasing LimitRequestFieldSize and LimitRequestLine but it is not working for the hosted Ubuntu 14.04 server. Specifically I modified the apache2.conf and set a high limit for them, restarted apache2 but didn't work..

I used the views post form [https://www.drupal.org/project/views_expost], which sends the query via POST method instead of GET method. The problem is that:

- Pager is not working [Items per page]. Setting it via UI does not alter it.
- I cannot save the Views query url for specific searches (no URL query due to POST method).

I would want to achieve the following:

- Generate variety of report by selecting different fields and filters.
- Save those searches(URL Query) and name them as different report.

Kindly suggest if there is an alternative to whether I can decrease the URL size via code, or achieve the required result differently. Thanks.